# How old is my house?

Tags: old-house

Have purchased an older home in Corinth, MS (No. Mississippi) and found that ALL the walls are T&G on the inside with shiplap on the exterior (the exterior has been resided with vinyl which will be replaced). Even the interior partitions are either T&G or wood boards (about 5" wide) including closets inside and out. The ceiling & floors are also all T&G and the roof is solid board as well. 
The studs etc are full dimensional lumber and rough.

I can't seem to get info from the Tax man or County recorder etc.

Any idea on the age of this based on construction methods?

The plumbing has been redone some time ago, so no toilets etc to help ID age.
Zero insulation and wiring minimal and dangerous!

I plan on removing exterior Shiplap to wire and insulate in the spring and hopefully be able to save enough to at least utilize some for an accent section or something.

Any help/advice appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to DIY. Generally we don't include names/email addresses in questions. Since your name & username are the same (they don't have to be), that is not an issue. As far as email, all communications are normally within the site. If you don't visit site for a day or two then you should get an automatic email if people have posted answers to your question.

Comment: Sounds very similar to a little cottage I own east of Atlanta. Shiplap on the outside (originally) T&G on the inside. The county records list mine as constructed in 1900 - which I'm assuming is just a guess. The plaque at the entrance to the village says something like 'established 1904', so it's probably within 10-15 years or so.

Comment: Check for the type of nails used in the framing.round nails became common in the late 1800’s.aluminum wire was used in the 1960’s  knob and tube wiring was in use in the late 1800’s-1930’s

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the exact kind of construction on a house we restored a few years ago. It was on a covered wagon route and was built about 1900, but I’m located “out west”.

I’d check with the local chapter of the Historic Preservation Office. (They’re a division of the Federal Department of the Interior.) They will have accurate info on type of construction in your area.

If you decide to restore it to their standards, there are some “big” tax savings, like your property taxes are frozen at the current value for 15 years or so, etc. However, you have to use their recommendations for windows, siding, etc. (Things like roofing can be anything, because it’s considered something that needs to be replaced from time to time, but check with them.)